# Clear `search everything` box on hide in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm

In the new version of Intellij, the 'search everything' box isn't cleared when it's closed (eg. I select one of the results and reopen it). However, since I like to use the middle-click-to-paste functionality, this is severely in the way of my workflow. Can this box be configured to clear as soon as it's hidden?

More clarification:

- I mean the box that pops up when you press shift twice
- I know I can just press delete, but I'm on Linux and there's this nice feature that when you middle click it pastes the last thing you selected; the problem now is that the box already contains some text and this text is selected as soon as the box opens so the thing that is pasted now is the thing that's already in the box that I dont want

Comment: Box selects all previous search term when you press `CTRL`+`F` again, so you can just press `Delete` or paste it over, it will get cleared automatically.